# Sync outlook messages with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have a vbscript that copy's Outlook 2003 messages into a folder in msg format.

The problems are:

- I am getting "path too long" errors for some *.msg . I wish to avoid these erros and I don't know how. ' On Error Resume Next is already on the script.
- I am getting only inbox messages, but I want all subfolders too;
- How can I extract this in *.txt and not in *.msg, in order to become lighter?

Here is my atual script. Thanks for the help!

```
    On Error Resume Next
Dim myNameSpace
Dim ofChosenFolder
Dim myOlApp
Dim myItem
Dim objItem
Dim myFolder
Dim strSubject
Dim strName
Dim strFile
Dim strReceived
Dim strSavePath

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Const olFolderInbox = 6 
    Set ofChosenFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
    strSavePath = "c:\test\"    'OBS! use a \ at the end of the path 


i = 1
For each Item in ofChosenFolder.Items
Set myItem = ofChosenFolder.Items(i)
strReceived = ArrangedDate(myitem.ReceivedTime)
' strSubject = myItem.Subject
strSubject = myitem.SenderName & "_" & myitem.Subject
strName = StripIllegalChar(strSubject)
strFile = strSavePath & strReceived & "_" & strName & ".msg"
If Not Len(strfile) > 256 then
myItem.SaveAs strfile, 3
Else
wscript.echo strfile & vbcrlf & "Path and filename too long."
End If
i = i + 1
next



Function StripIllegalChar(strInput)

'***************************************************
'Simple function that removes illegal file system
'characters.
'***************************************************

Set RegX = New RegExp

RegX.pattern = "[\" & chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
RegX.IgnoreCase = True
RegX.Global = True

StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(strInput, "")
Set RegX = nothing

End Function


Function ArrangedDate(strDateInput)

'***************************************************
'This function re-arranges the date data in order
'for it to display in chronilogical order in a
'sorted list in the file system. It also removes
'illegal file system characters and replaces them
'with dashes.
'Example:
'Input: 2/26/2004 7:07:33 AM
'Output: 2004-02-26_AM-07-07-33
'***************************************************

Dim strFullDate
Dim strFullTime
Dim strAMPM
Dim strTime
Dim strYear
Dim strMonthDay
Dim strMonth
Dim strDay
Dim strDate
Dim strDateTime
Dim RegX

If not Left(strDateInput, 2) = "10" Then
If not Left(strDateInput, 2) = "11" Then
If not Left(strDateInput, 2) = "12" Then
strDateInput = "0" & strDateInput
End If
End If
End If

strFullDate = Left(strDateInput, 10)

If Right(strFullDate, 1) = " " Then
strFullDate = Left(strDateInput, 9)
End If

strFullTime = Replace(strDateInput,strFullDate & " ","")

If Len(strFullTime) = 10 Then
strFullTime = "0" & strFullTime
End If

strAMPM = Right(strFullTime, 2)

strTime = strAMPM & "-" & Left(strFullTime, 8)

strYear = Right(strFullDate,4)

strMonthDay = Replace(strFullDate,"/" & strYear,"")

strMonth = Left(strMonthDay, 2)

strDay = Right(strMonthDay,len(strMonthDay)-3)

If len(strDay) = 1 Then
strDay = "0" & strDay
End If

strDate = strYear & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay

'strDateTime = strDate & "_" & strTime
strDateTime = strDate

Set RegX = New RegExp

RegX.pattern = "[\:\/\ ]"
RegX.IgnoreCase = True
RegX.Global = True

ArrangedDate = RegX.Replace(strDateTime, "-")

Set RegX = nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to truncate the file name appropriately (strName)
2. Move your code that processes a folder into a sub that take fodler that takes folder as parameter and call it for ofChosenFolder as well as all of its child fodlers in the ofChosenFolder.Folders collection.
3. You are calling SaveAs..., 3 - 3 here is olMsg. Specify olTxt (= 0).

Off the top of my head:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6 
Set ofChosenFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
trSavePath = "c:\test\"  

ProcessFolder ofChosenFolder, trSavePath 

sub ProcessFolder(folder, path)
  For each Item in folder.Items

    strReceived = ArrangedDate(Item.ReceivedTime)
    strSubject = Item.SenderName & "_" &Item .Subject
    strName = StripIllegalChar(strSubject)
    strFile = strSavePath & strReceived & "_" & strName & ".msg"
    If Not Len(strfile) > 256 then
      Item.SaveAs strfile, 3
    Else
      wscript.echo strfile & vbcrlf & "Path and filename too long."
    End If
  next

  for each subfolder in folder.Folders
    ProcessFolder(subfolder, trSavePath & subfolder.Name & "\"
  next
end sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for trying to help me!
I am not that scriting expert, so could you please help me on where should I remove the bad code part and where should I add the right code please? Many thanks!

Comment: I still need detailed help for the other 2 plz ... exact codes perhaps! Thx

Comment: Error on line 11, char 46. Error: Code 800A0401- Expected end of statement

Comment: Which line is that? As I mentioned, this is off the top of my head, I did not actually run the code. This is just to give you an idea what needs to be done and how.